# PHP. How to get a bimonthly recurring event?

Tags: php

I'm trying many approaches but then I get stuck half way.

Let's say order was created today. I need to display when the next recurring order will happen. So I have order created June 13, 2012. Then I have set the schedule to bimonthly recurring order, every 1st of month. How to calculate when the next recurring order will happen? The answer is August 1st.

If someone can outline an approach it would be very useful, it doesn't have to be code. This is what I have so far...

```
    // first, get starting date
    $start_date_month = date('m', strtotime($start_date));

    // get this year
    $this_year = date('Y');

    // if this month is december, next month is january
    $this_month = date('m', $timestamp_month);
    if($this_month == 12){
      $next_month = 1;
    // if this month is not december add 1 to get next month
    }else{
      $next_month = $this_month + 1;
    }

    // get array of months where recurring orders will happen
    $months = array();
    for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++) {
      $add_month = $start_date_month+(2*$i); // 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12
      if($add_month == 13){$add_month = 1;$year = $this_year+1;}
      elseif($add_month == 14){$add_month = 2;$year = $this_year+1;}
      elseif($add_month == 15){$add_month = 3;$year = $this_year+1;}
      elseif($add_month == 16){$add_month = 4;$year = $this_year+1;}
      elseif($add_month == 17){$add_month = 5;$year = $this_year+1;}
      elseif($add_month == 18){$add_month = 6;$year = $this_year+1;}
      elseif($add_month == 19){$add_month = 7;$year = $this_year+1;}
      elseif($add_month == 20){$add_month = 8;$year = $this_year+1;}
      else{$year = $this_year;}
      echo $what_day.'-'.$add_month.'-'.$year.'<br />';
      $months[] = $add_month;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($months);
    echo '</pre>';
```

**I don't want to simply find what's the date in two months from now. Let's say order created June 1. Next recurring order is August 1. Then let's say now, today is September 1st, but next recurring order is October 1st. See my dilemma?**

Comment: Do you want **only** the next recurring date from today, or all of the recurring dates from the creation up to and including the next one from today?

Comment: I don't see your dilemma.  Why does September 1st matter?  How does it relate to the recurring order problem?

Comment: Because if order was created today June 13 is easy to come up with the next recurring order. It's also easy to come up with an array of all next 6 recurring orders. Now, if today would be September 1st, how do you calculate the next recurring order? All that needs to be calculated is ONE date, just the next recurring order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take the current month, so since it's June, we get 6. `6 mod 2 == 0`. Next month is July, we get 7. `7 mod 2 == 1`.

So just check if `current month % 2 == (first month % 2)`.

Then just check if it's the 1st of the month.

In PHP modulus is defined with the percentage symbol.

```
$month = date('n');
$createdMonth = 6;
if($month % 2 == $createdMonth % 2){
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: it's Bimonthly, every two months

Comment: Exactly, this method would work. If you started on June (6), it would skip July and then August (8) would reoccur the event. (6 % 2) == (8 % 2)

Comment: And if you were to start it in July (7), it would next reoccur in September because `9 % 2` and `7 % 2` are equal, but it would skip over August since `8 % 2` is not equal to `7 % 2`

Comment: Ok, let's say now 3 months go by, and we are on September 5. The next recurring order is supposed to happen on October. How do you work that? It's not just one order, is a recurring order that it's supposed to happen **every** two months.

Comment: It would happen in October because October is an even month and `10 % 2` is equal to `6 % 2`

Comment: it helped me on another function i needed, which was to check if the recurring order is supposed to happen today. thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You might find the library called [When](https://github.com/tplaner/When) useful for this (I'm the author).

Here is code which will get you the next 2 recurring monthly dates (from todays date):

```
include 'When.php';

$r = new When();
$r->recur(new DateTime(), 'monthly')
  ->count(2)
  ->interval(2) // every other month
  ->bymonthday(array(1));

while($result = $r->next())
{
    echo $result->format('c') . '<br />';
}

// output
// 2012-08-01T13:33:33-04:00
// 2012-10-01T13:33:33-04:00
```

Taking this a step further, you likely only want to find the 2 first business days:

```
include 'When.php';

$r = new When();
$r->recur(new DateTime(), 'monthly')
  ->count(2)
  ->interval(2)                                 // every other month
  ->byday(array('MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR'))  // week days only
  ->bymonthday(array(1, 2, 3))                  // the first weekday will fall on one of these days
  ->bysetpos(array(1));                         // only return one per month

while($result = $r->next())
{
    echo $result->format('c') . '<br />';
}

// output
// 2012-08-01T13:33:33-04:00
// 2012-10-01T13:33:33-04:00
```

Also note, the code is currently under a rewrite -- it works well but it is a little confusing and not well documented.

Answer (score 2):

I got this:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$target_date = $today->modify("first day of +2 months");

echo "Your event is on " . $target_date->format("d/m/Y") . "!";
```

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` to the rescue:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$d = new DateTime('2012-01-31');
$d->modify('first day of +2 months');
echo $d->format('r'), "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want the next six orders:

```
$order_date = '6/13/2012';
$start      = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($order_date));

$order_count = 6;

$future_orders = array();

$next = strtotime('+2 months', strtotime($start));
while(count($future_orders) < $order_count){
    $future_orders[] = date('m/d/Y',$next);
    $next = strtotime('+2 months', $next);
}
```

This can, obviously, be improved upon, but it should get you started ...